# php how to use proc_open to pipe the content of a variable to the process

Tags: php, command-line, pipe, proc-open

from a `php` script I am trying to run an external command which is taking its input from a previous command with a pipe (at os level).
The command I want to use is `pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout myfile.pdf -`.
I have been able to get `proc_open` working with a file to read for input.

But I getting my input from a variable not from a file. The main command accepts its input from a pipe (at os level) like this : `cat myfile.pdf | pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout - -` to give the same result.

I would like to directly send the content of this variable without having to create a temporary file.

Can it be done ? and how ?

Here is a working example of what I don't want to do:

```
$data = <<<EOD
    Hello
    world!
    EOD;
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "myPDF");

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);

$cmd = "cat $tmpfname | grep -i hello";
$proc=proc_open($cmd,
array(
  array("pipe","r"), //stdin
  array("pipe","w"), //stdout
  array("pipe","w") //stderr
),
$pipes);

$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
$stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
var_dump($stdout);
var_dump($stderr);
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
$exit_status = proc_close($proc);
echo $exit_status;
unlink($tmpfname);
```

how to get rid of the file manipulation part ? how get it working with `$cmd = "grep -i hello";` instead of `$cmd = "cat $tmpfname | grep -i hello";` ? how to use `$data` with `proc_open` ? (please no comment about `grep` or alternative to it, it is not the final command I plan to use, it is only to provide a quite portable example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using echo instead of cat? So your command will be like:

```
$cmd = "echo $tmpfname | grep -i hello";
#       ^^^^
```

**Update**

Or, why you don't simply pipe your data to your proc_open stdin? like the following:

```
$file = file_get_contents('your/pdf/file.pdf'); // or whatever your variable is

$pipes = [];
$process = proc_open(
    "pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout - -",
    array(
        0 => array("pipe", 'r'),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
     ),
    $pipes,
);

fwrite($pipes[0], $file);
fclose($pipes[0]);

echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
echo "\n===========\n";
```

Comment: it would be `echo $data`, but it seems ok only with text content. But not with my data which is binary. I tried  to enclose the variable in single quote, double quotes, but I get an error : `"sh: 548: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: What about using the `-e` and `-n` flags with echo?

Comment: It is the solution I was looking for. In all my attempts it was stucked doing nothing. I didn't think to  `fclose($pipes[0])` before accessing `$pipes[1]`